# Verify User Password Matches Password in Database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, passwords

I'm not finding what I'm looking for.. so I'm just going to ask.

I have a database in which a program is inputting passwords into the database for users using "password()" I believe. I don't care what their password is.. I just want to know how to see if it matches what they're logging in with.

```
User: testuser

Pass: *73707352065FCC66935AE2E3883E52F483C3CCC8

if(password = dbpassword){}
```

How can I make that work? I've tried:

```
if(password($_POST['password']) == $result['password']){}
```

But that doesn't work.. and little variations of that as well. Can't figure it out. Please help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the passwords are hashed/salted in some way.

PHP now has built-in [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify) functions you should be using, along with simple guides on how to implement.

Comment: So that will likely be my answer, but I'm having issues. I was running php5 and that's why I can't use that.. but I just upgraded my appserv to 2.6 and now nothing's working at all. -_-